# d3-force update radius of forceCollide after initializing graph

Tags: d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

This question is a follow-up on a previous one titled "D3-Force updating parameters after initializing graph" ([D3-Force updating parameters after initializing graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995816/d3-force-updating-parameters-after-initializing-graph)) and that @altocumulus answered.

I am trying to update the simulation forces after modifying the radius of some nodes. However, when I call on `forceCollide` to account for the changes it does not work.

The graph first initiates correctly, using `forceCollide` and a function to have the force correspond with the radius:

```
var forceCollide = d3.forceCollide()
.radius(function(d){return d.radius;})
.iterations(2)
.strength(0.95);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
.velocityDecay(velocityDecay)
.force("collide", forceCollide);
```

I then modify the `d.radius` object and want `forceCollide` to reflect the changes. However, when I call on the `forceCollide` again it does not work:

```
forceCollide.radius(function(d){
d.radius;})
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not actually update the radius. You are just re-setting the callback used to determine the radius, which doesn't even change compared to what it was before. Even if it *did* change, this would not trigger your update, because the radii won't be re-evaluated based on your updated data.

When updating the distance callback of the link force, the force itself will get initialized. A look at the [source](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/src/link.js#L111-L113) shows a call to `initializeDistance()`:

```
force.distance = function(_) {
  return arguments.length ? (distance = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), initializeDistance(), force) : distance;
};
```

The same holds true for many other updates of other forces' parameters.

Looking at the source of the [collide](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/src/collide.js#L93-L95) force, however, one notices that there is no initialization invoked:

```
force.radius = function(_) {
  return arguments.length ? (radius = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), force) : radius;
};
```

Since your callback doesn't change you won't need to call `forceCollide.radius()` again. Instead you need to call

```
forceCollide.initialize(simulation.nodes());
```

This will re-evaluate the radii based on your updated data.